# How to pass a file list to zcat as a bash variable?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to pass a single stream of `zcat` output into a bash pipeline. Let's use `wc -l` as my pipeline for this example.

```
zcat -f /var/log/log.3.gz /var/log/log.2.gz /var/log/log.1.gz /var/log/log | wc -l
```

actually returns the number of lines.

```
paths="/var/log/log.3.gz /var/log/log.2.gz /var/log/log.1.gz /var/log/log"
zcat -f "${paths}" | wc -l
```

> gzip: /var/log/log.3.gz /var/log/log.2.gz /var/log/log.1.gz
> /var/log/log.gz: No such file or directory

How can I combine all of these files to stdout so that my pipeline only makes one pass without intermediate files? My attempt at passing the entire string results in `.gz` appended to the variable as if thats the single argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lists are assigned with the `var=('first value' 'second value'...)` syntax in `bash`.

```
paths=(/var/log/log.3.gz /var/log/log.2.gz /var/log/log.1.gz /var/log/log)
zcat -f -- "${paths[@]}" | wc -l
```

Beware that of `$path` contains an empty list, `zcat -f -- "${paths[@]}"` will become `zcat -f --` and when not passed any file name argument, `zcat` will read its stdin instead of not producing any output at all.

To work around that, you could do instead:

```
{ (( ${#paths[@]} == 0 )) || zcat -f -- "${paths[@]}"; } | wc -l
```

Or:

```
zcat -f -- </dev/null "${paths[@]}" | wc -l
```

If you wanted to concatenate the `/var/log/log*` files in reverse numeric order, you'd rather use the `zsh` shell than `bash` and do:

```
zcat -f /var/log/log*(nOn) | wc -l
```

(that's `n`umerical `o`rder (capital `O` for reverse) by `n`ame).

And no need for the workaround described above; if there's no matching file, you'd get:

```
$ zcat -f /var/log/log*(nOn) | wc -l
zsh: no matches found: /var/log/log*(nOn)
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the variable unquoted will enable the shell to perform word splitting and filename generation. Since you only want the first effect, you can disable the latter:

```bsh
paths="/var/log/log.3.gz /var/log/log.2.gz /var/log/log.1.gz /var/log/log"
(
  set -f
  zcat -f $paths | wc -l   # variable is unquoted
)
```

I added parentheses so the setting is only in effect for the lifetime of that subshell.

Clearly, allowing the shell to do word splitting means it will break if any of the pathnames contains a space.